# Powershell - multiple commands to multiple files

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-2.0

Hoping someone can help me finish off this script.  I have a folder full of *.imp (plain text - csv exports) files that I need to modify.  These files are updated on a schedule, so this Powershell script will be updated on a schedule too, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is where I've gotten so far...

```
$InputFiles = Get-Item "C:\scripts\*.imp"
$OldString  = '@##'
$NewString  = '"'
$InputFiles | ForEach {
(Get-Content -Path $_.FullName).Replace($OldString,$NewString) | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName
(Get-Content -Path $_.FullName).-notmatch '(^[\s,-]*$)|(rows\s*affected)' | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName
(Get-Content -Path $_.FullName).-notmatch 'HeaderRow' | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName
}
```

If I leave the first Get-Content line, it works, but adding the other two don't.
Can anyway help me with this?
Thanks 
Luke

Comment: Remove the dot from `.-notmatch` *(replace with space)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Lieven points out you need to remove the `.` reference operator in the second and third statement:

```
$InputFiles = Get-Item "C:\scripts\*.imp"
$OldString  = '@##'
$NewString  = '"'
$InputFiles | ForEach {
  (Get-Content -Path $_.FullName).Replace($OldString,$NewString) | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName
  (Get-Content -Path $_.FullName) -notmatch '(^[\s,-]*$)|(rows\s*affected)' | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName
  (Get-Content -Path $_.FullName) -notmatch 'HeaderRow' | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName
}
```

Instead of reading and writing the file from disk three times, you could chain all the operations:

```
$InputFiles = Get-Item "C:\scripts\*.imp"
$OldString  = '@##'
$NewString  = '"'
$InputFiles | ForEach {
  (Get-Content -Path $_.FullName).Replace($OldString,$NewString) -notmatch '(^[\s,-]*$)|(rows\s*affected)' -notmatch 'HeaderRow' | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lieven and Mathias.  I used the tidier version you supplied Mathias, and it works wonders.  Thank you for your gracious help!